# Estoy creando una restricción de usuarios y cuando trato de ejecutarlo el while se salta el switch y no retorna nada

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms, aplicación-web

*ACÁ ES DONDE TENGO EL ERROR POR LA PARTE DEL SWITCH*

```
void Permisos(int Idrol)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_permisos", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IdRol", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Idrol;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            bool Crear, Leer, Modificar, Eliminar;
```

*CUANDO EL CODIGO LLEGA ACÁ, NO ENTRA AL SWITCH*

```
            foreach (GridViewRow fila in datos.Rows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader[0].ToString())   
                    {
                        case "Crear":
                            Crear = Convert.ToBoolean(reader[1].ToString());

                            if (Crear)
                            {
                                btnCreate.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btnCreate.Visible = false;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Modificar":
                            Modificar = Convert.ToBoolean(reader[1].ToString());
                            Button btn2 = fila.FindControl("btnUpdate") as Button;

                            if (Modificar)
                            {
                                btn2.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btn2.Visible = false;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Leer":
                            Leer = Convert.ToBoolean(reader[1].ToString());
                            Button btn3 = fila.FindControl("btnRead") as Button;
                            if (Leer)
                            {
                                btn3.Visible = true;
                                datos.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btn3.Visible = false;
                                datos.Visible = false;
                            }
                            break;

                        case "Eliminar":
                            Eliminar = Convert.ToBoolean(reader[1].ToString());
                            Button btn4 = fila.FindControl("btnDelete") as Button;

                            if (Eliminar)
                            {
                                btn4.Visible = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                btn4.Visible = false;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
```

> SE PASA DEFRENTE A ESTA SECCION

```
               }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Mi pregunta es por qué sucede esto, cuando checo en los detalles de la ejecución me sale que no retorna nada ya me aseguré en la base de datos si los nombres están bien escritos y no veo diferencias en ninguna parte en `Idrol` me devuelve 0 cuando debería devolver 1 o 0
y en el caso que vuelva 0 se deben ocultar botones *restricciones* y aun devolviendo 0 se muestran los todos los botones y el DataGrid..

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_permisos] ( @IdRol int ) as
 begin 
   select Nombre, Estado 
    from RolesPermisos 
    inner join Permisos on Permisos.IdPermiso = RolesPermisos.IdPermiso 
    where IdRol = @IdRol 
  end
```

Comment: Pon el código del Store Procedure

Comment: @Yussef el código ya estaba puesto pero aun así daba otro error

Comment: Primero, no entiendo bien la parte que haces un foreach del datagrid y luego un White del reader.Read. por ejemplo si el datagrid tiene dos filas. La primera fila entrar al while del reader y lee hasta el final, por lo tanto la segunda fila del grid va a encontrar el reader en estado invalido. Ahora a fin de ver si retorna algo antes de entrar al While verifica si el reader tiene resultados con  ``if(reader.HasRows)`` previo al whie. Y con ello ves si realmente ha leído algo.

Comment: Y que contiene el datagrid?